# How to get category (folder) Id of SSJS activities

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, rest, marketingcloudapi

I tries to create SSJS activity using REST API. Body of request looks like this:

```
{    
    "name": "ActivityName",
    "key": "ActivityKey",
    "description": "",
    "script": "Blablabla",
    "categoryId": 123456
}
```

But, `categoryId` field is required, and I don't know how I can get it using API (any API). So, the question is: how to get `categoryId` of SSJS activities? Ideally is to retrieve root `categoryId`, but honestly, I hope to get at least any `categoryId` through API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of your SSJS Activities folder via the category type of `ssjsactivity` on the folder structure endpoint:

```
GET /email/v1/categories?catType=ssjsactivity
Host: {{subDomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{auth_token}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

This will return an array of the folders and IDs of your SSJS Activities. Like below:

```json
{
    "count": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 50,
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/v1/categories/?catType=ssjsactivity&$page=1&$pageSize=50"
        }
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "categoryId": 123456,
            "parentCatId": 0,
            "modifiedBy": XXXXXXX,
            "objectId": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "createDate": "2029-12-09T12:33:28.133",
            "modifiedDate": "2029-12-09T12:33:28.133",
            "catType": "SSJSActivity",
            "name": "Scripts",
            "categoryDesc": "",
            "iconType": "SSJSActivity"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that forks just fine. can you help me one more time? do you know what is catType for query activities? cause I also need this done for query activities as well

Comment: Found it, it's queryactivity